# How to check if the user grants File System permission in Settings?

Tags: uwp

My app really needs File System permission (`broadFileSystemAccess`) but unfortunately, this settings can be Off by user in Windows Settings > Privacy > File System. Is there a good way to check that the setting is On at run time to remind user? The probing code

```
    try {
        auto file = co_await winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(L"C:\\Windows\\regedit.exe");
    } catch (winrt::hresult_error const& e) {
         // Show message dialog
    }
```

doesn't seems great to me since user might install Windows on different drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no clear API to detect if the file system is open, you can only check it when you get the file.

However, you can make a judgment during the check process. If you use the try-catch statement to catch an error of type `UnauthorizedAccessException`, the file system is not open. Tested to give priority to unauthorized errors even when accessing non-existent files.

Comment: I want to remind the user that they may need to check the Settings. The issue with checking on every `catch` is that I have to show a Dialog and either split the processing code (*resume* after the check) in a separate method or duplicate it.

Comment: You can choose to encapsulate the entire processing flow (detection file-> pop-up message dialog), or you can perform a check after the `MainPage` is loaded. If it is not authorized, ask the user to authorize and use a variable in the application to remember the check status. When you need to use related functions in the future, you don't need to repeat the check the file. You only need to check the status of this variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will go with that.